# How to do a speed boost?

Tags: macos, pixeljunk-shooter

I've seen youtube videos and people do boost to improve their velocity. How can I do that on the OS X version? There is special button combo to do it?

Comment: "How do to that con the computer?" What?

Comment: @Brian Haha sorry, I'm mixing too many languages lately. Edited

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying now.

Comment: On a controller, you push both analog sticks in the same direction, but I'm not sure about keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the developer](http://steamcommunity.com/app/255870/discussions/0/666826703975288127/#c666827315262210950), you need to actively aim and move in the same direction in order to boost. With a controller, this can be achieved by pointing both sticks in the same direction, but requires a bit more precision with the mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Humm... maybe in the console you can get the boost earlier, because looking at the videos I can't reach the max velocity that fast.

Comment: @SysDragon Are you using a controller?

Comment: @Nolonar No, the keyboard